# Select only latest datetime entry by date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of logdata (the db is MS SQL Server 2012):

```
id  full_name   log_date  
1   Name1       2020-01-07 06:43:35.283  
2   Name2       2020-01-07 08:12:26.153  
3   Name3       2020-01-07 08:23:38.640  
4   Name4       2020-01-07 08:27:03.953  
5   Name1       2020-01-08 09:31:35.393  
6   Name5       2020-01-08 09:44:46.753  
7   Name2       2020-01-08 10:16:30.340  
8   Name6       2020-01-09 06:33:41.220  
9   Name3       2020-01-09 10:35:25.843  
10  Name1       2020-01-09 15:45:58.753
```

log_date is datetime.

I want to get only the last logtime for each date in the table. The result should be:

```
id  full_name   log_date  
4   Name4       2020-01-07 08:27:03.953  
7   Name2       2020-01-08 10:16:30.340  
10  Name1       2020-01-09 15:45:58.753
```

Thanks in advance.

Aage Svanholm

Comment: Please show us your attempted query

Comment: My attempted queries don't work. I want only the latest entry for each date. I don't mind if the names is excluded in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()` with `partition by` the date `convert(date, log_date)`

```
select *
from   (
            select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by convert(date, log_date) 
                                                  order by log_date desc)
            from   yourtable
       ) d
where  d.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But it is not quite right. Joseph's answer gets it right.

Comment: I'm sorry., I was too hasty here. This works too. It was a matter of the sorting of dates. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that I can think of to do this would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE log_date in (
    SELECT MAX(log_date)
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(date,log_Date)
)
```

But maybe this is not the exact right way to do it.

Comment: *Just FYI*: this query wont work as expected if two log entries have the exact same date and hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Then, it will return two entries for that particular day

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM logdata 
WHERE log_date in (
    SELECT max(log_date)
    FROM logdata 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(date, log_date)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* way is probably:

```
select top (1) with ties l.*
from logdata l
order by row_number() over (partition by convert(date, log_date) order by log_date desc);
```

That is, no subqueries are required.

With the right indexes (i.e. on `logdata(log_date)`), the most efficient is probably:

```
select ld.*
from logdata ld
where ld.log_date = (select max(ld2.log_date)
                     from logdata ld2
                     where ld2.log_date >= convert(date, ld.log_date) and
                           ld2.log_date < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, ld2.log_date))
                    );
```

`row_number()` is the "canonical" method, fully supported by standard SQL.  However, it needs to map the row number back to every row so that is a bit more work than the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of scenarios you have to use Sub Queries. 
Lets take the table name as YourTable.

First you should get the Latest date from each day. Use below Query for that.

```
SELECT MAX(log_date)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,log_date)
```

Then use below query for final result and the above mentioned query is will be used as a sub query.

Final Query is below.

`SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE log_date in 
    (
    SELECT MAX(log_date)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,log_date)
    )`